# Subset a large matrix based on a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm working with some genomic files in R. I have a large matrix formatted like the example below where columns are sample and rows are genes (the real matrix has 205 columns and more than 22k rows.

```
          GSM1304852  GSM1304853 GSM1304854 GSM1304855
1007_s_at  2.3945368  2.27518369  2.1611630  1.9641833
1053_at    0.1051084  0.06160802  0.3421762  0.3593916
117_at    -0.4597124 -0.52310349 -0.4436059 -0.6370277
121_at     0.9333566  1.13180904  0.9975700  1.0079778
```

I also have a dataframe formatted like the example below where `geo_accession` is the same id that can be found in the first row of the matrix.

```
                    title geo_accession Age    Disease_State Gender  pH  PMI Race RIN      tissue
GSM1304852 bipolar_hip_10    GSM1304852  52 bipolar disorder      M 6.7 23.5    W 6.3 hippocampus
GSM1304853 bipolar_hip_11    GSM1304853  50 bipolar disorder      F 6.4 11.7    W 6.8 hippocampus
GSM1304854 bipolar_hip_12    GSM1304854  28 bipolar disorder      F 6.3 22.3    W 7.7 hippocampus
GSM1304855 bipolar_hip_13    GSM1304855  55 bipolar disorder      F 6.4 17.5    W 7.6 hippocampus
GSM1304856 bipolar_hip_14    GSM1304856  58 bipolar disorder      M 6.8 27.7    W 7.0 hippocampus
GSM1304857 bipolar_hip_15    GSM1304857  28 bipolar disorder      M 6.2 27.4    W 7.7 hippocampus
```

I need to subset all the columns in the matrix associated with a certain tissue(in the full dataframe there are 3 kinds of tissue), therefore at the end, I need to have 3 matrices.

For example: from the matrix I want to take only the column associated with `hippocampus`:

```
matrix # an R matrix object
DataFrame # an R dataframe

DFhip <- DataFrame[ which(tissue == 'hippocampus',]
GSMlist <- DFhip$geo_accesion

MatrixHip <- matrix[GSMlist,] # I know this is the wrong syntax, it's just to let you understand
```

I'm relatively new to R and I'm not used to subset matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but if you want to subset a dataframe for ine row just use:

```
    data1<-data[data[1] %in% c("GSM1304852","GSM1304855")]
```

on data[1] is the number of column in the dataframe that you need to subset

Comment: Ok, for example: I want to find all the `geo_accession` that comes from the hippocampus, therefore I filter my dataframe and I take only the `geo_accession` column. Now I want to take all the column from the matrix that match with the instances filtered

Answer (score 0):

Since the colnames in your first matrix are the same as geo_accession, you could use the latter directly to subset the columns :

```
hippocamups <- your_large_matrix[, your_dataframe$geo_accession[your_dataframe$tissue == "Hippocapmus"] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix has defined colnames, try this:

```
lapply(function(x) {
 matrix[, unique(df$geo_accession[df$tissue == x])]
}, x = unique(df$tissue))
```

Matrix is you matrix, df is your data frame.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, they helped me a lot. Everything works with his two lines of code:

```
hippocampus <- filter(GSMdata, tissue == 'hippocampus')$geo_accession
hippocampus <- data[, hippocamups]
```